# Issues with event delegation on same container

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I have a function, simplified like this:

```
var fooFunction = function($container, data) {
  $container.data('foobarData', data);

  $container.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var data = $(e.delegateTarget).data('foobarData');
    var $target = $(e.currentTarget);

    if (typeof data.validateFunction === 'function' && !data.validateFunction(e)) {
      return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Do stuff
    console.log(data.returnText);
  });
};

fooFunction('.same-container', {
  validateFunction: function(event) {
    return $(e.currentTarget).closest('.type-companies').length ? true : false;
  },
  returnText: 'Hello Company!',
});

fooFunction('.same-container', {
  validateFunction: function(event) {
    return $(e.currentTarget).closest('.type-humans').length ? true : false;
  },
  returnText: 'Hello Human!',
})
```

I am using event delegation on the same container (`.same-container`) with a custom `validateFunction()` to validate if the code in `// Do stuff` should run.

For each `fooFunction()` initiation, I have some different logic that will get called on `// Do stuff`. The issue is that those two event delegations conflict. It seems that only one of them is called and overwrites the other one.

How can I have multiple event delegations with the option to define via a custom validateFunction which one should be called. I use `preventDefault() + stopPropagation()` so on click on a `<a>`, nothing happens as long as `validateFunction()` returns `true`.

Comment: You should mention that you're using jQuery.

Comment: @EduardoEscobar true

Also I was gonna suggest using `element.addEventListener(...)` before I saw the jQuery

That always worked for me in terms of having multiple functions for one event

Comment: Every time you call `fooFunction()` it overwrites the `foobarData` data of the container.

Comment: By the way, in your code $container would be a string, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're overwriting `$(e.delegateTarget).data('foobarData')` every time.

Instead, you could add the options to an array, which you loop over until a match is found.

```js
var fooFunction = function($container, data) {
  var oldData = $container.data('foobarData', data);
  if (oldData) { // Already delegated, add the new data
    oldData.push(data);
    $container.data('foobarData', oldData);
  } else { // First time, create initial data and delegate handler
    $container.data('foobarData', [data]);
    $container.on('click', 'a', function(e) {
      var data = $(e.delegateTarget).data('foobarData');
      var $target = $(e.currentTarget);
      var index = data.find(data => typeof data.validateFunction === 'function' && !data.validateFunction(e));
      if (index > -1) {
        var foundData = data[index]

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        // Do stuff
        console.log(foundData.returnText);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That my `.data()` was called twice and therefore the second call overwrites the first one, I did not see! This will fix it! Thanks!